# Xcode crashes whenever I try and Refactor

Tags: iphone, xcode

I get the following internal error message whenever I try and Refactor:

```
File:    /SourceCache/DevToolsIDE/DevToolsIDE-1708/pbxinterface/Snapshots/XCDirectorySnapshotSyncOperation.m
Line:    137
Object:    <XCDirectorySnapshotSyncOperation:0x201d51560>
Method:    _setErrorMessage:



Assertion failed: nil == _errorMessage
```

I have tried everything.  I re-installed a new version of Xcode, I have tried re-installing the older version of Xcode nothing works?

Comment: What version of xCode? Maybe file a bug on Apple's radar.

Comment: All versions have the same issue

Comment: I got the sane problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the cache file referenced in the error and trying again.
The cache file could have become corrupt and causing the crash.
Also report this to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Where do I find this bug - I can't seem to locate this directory?

Comment: Snapshots are usually stored at `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/SnapshotRepository.sparseimage`. Try deleting the sparse image and trying again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but can't find that file. Any idea where it might be on newer versions?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I doubt this file still exists in recent versions of Xcode -- this question and answer is from 2010.

Comment: @Jasarien yes I'm aware :) I was just wondering whether there is a "modern" version of it, as I'm having the same problem with a modern project and none of the conventional solutions (clean build folder, delete derived data, remove user data from workspace/project etc.) worked.

Answer (score 2):

This was as simple as setting my target back to 5.1 (I was trying for 3 for max backwards compatibility)  ... I assume I can set it back to target 3 before deployment , but leaving it a 5.1 whilst refactoring definately helped me